# My LG washing Machine Model F1203CDP has error DE

Tags: washing-machine

I read online that DE error is due to Door Not Locking properly. I also read its  because of drain hose which I don't understand. Can any one help me in this regard how can drain hose cause DE error and how to resolve it. Also let me know if I'm  doing wrong by draining the washing machine water directly into the floor trap in kitchen. is this causing DE error??

Answer (score 1):

DE is usually related to the door. It could be a broken hinge, a faulty door magnet, a door not properly closed or an overloaded machine that is applying too much pressure to the door.

It can also be a drain issue. Using a floor drain is acceptable as long as you also have a standpipe that is at least 3 feet high. Otherwise, the water would run out of the washer when the water level inside the machine reaches the height of the standpipe. If your hose is too low or something is restricting the water flow, that could be throwing the code.

Comment: Thank You for your reply. I'm trying to replace the door switch lock. Regarding drain, it's been draining as usual without any problem . So the error cause is due to door switch . Thanks Again.

Comment: @AmmarAhmed – if the answer helped, please mark it as accepted by adding check mark - see the [tour].